# Function won't store a value

Tags: python, scope

I am trying to write a Python script with a function.

The code below works as expected, it prints 3.

```
def function(a,b):
  k = a+b
  print(k)

a = 1
b = 2
function(a,b)
```

But when I move the print statement outside the function like this, it won't work.

```
def function(a,b):
  k = a+b

a = 1
b = 2
function(a,b)

print(k)  # -> NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how to not have the print statement inside the function and still get this code to work?

Comment: Note that "it won't work" is not a helpful problem statement. In this case the error is obvious so I've added it in for you, but in the future it will help a lot to make a [mre].

Comment: BTW, having variables named `a` and `b` both inside and outside the function is bad practice because of [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`k` is a local variable defined inside the function.

**Case 1: Just return it:**

```
def function(a,b):
    k = a+b
    return k # just return, does not make it global

a = 1
b = 2
k = function(a,b)
# 3
print(k) # variable was returned by the function
```

---

**Case 2: Make it global:**

```
def function(a,b):
    global k #makes it global
    k = a+b

function(a,b)
print(k) # it is global so you can access it
```

Please read more [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't a better thing be to *return* `k`? No reason to help beginning programmers to successfully write bad code.

Comment: I agree with @JohnColeman. This doesn't seem like what OP wants or needs.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I suspect that it *is* what OP wants (perhaps without knowing so), though they shouldn't be encouraged in such desires. On the other hand, there are valid use cases for `global`, so it doesn't hurt to make them aware of it.

Comment: I agree about the return statement. I have edited my answer

Comment: @JohnColeman Of course there are valid use cases, but the fact that there also aren't should be made very clear. You are right in that we can't be certain what OP wants.

Comment: @makis Now I'm curious. Does making it global **and** returning the variable have any particular effect? I'm not familiar with the technicalities of `global`.

Comment: No need for both. I have now included both possible scenarii

Comment: added comments in my code to make everything more clear. cheers

Comment: Shouldn't case 1 show how to actually make the code work that way, by assigning the result to a variable and then printing it?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of setting a global variable (global variables are often bad), why not *return* the result and print it?

Something like

```
def function(a,b)
  return a+b

print(function(1,2))
```